# Regex to match URL within long string

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have a string here:

> Good Day,I would like to $1000 (for example remove these parenthesis) $test $ asdf [and remove these brackets] inquire the price of the 3D product name here. Currently we have the other product name here which I believe has an accuracy of about 0.0005 199 200. http://www.example.com this is a test

I have a regex linked here: https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/7

Which has this regex in it:

```
[^\w\s|https?:\/\/.\-*\s]|\W*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

What I'm trying to do now is have it match the entire URL. It seems that my `|https?:\/\/.\-*\s` is finding the url, but it's ignoring it, possible because the `^` at the start of that set? I could use some help having it match URLs within a string.

Comment: It's a test string :) And `https?` should capture both?

Comment: It depends on your input strings really. You could as well come up with sth. like `~(https?://\S+)~`, see [a demo here](https://regex101.com/r/aI4uW3/2), though not for JavaScript, admittedly (your question is tagged with different languages anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, you could come up with a regex like:

```
~(https?://\S+)~
# start / end with the tilde ~ as delimiters
# look for http/https, followed by ://
# match anything that is not a whitespace
# capture everything into a group
```

For JavaScript this would come down to (mind the escaped forward slashes):

```
(https?:\/\/\S+)
```

This is not very specific and heavily depends on your input strings, though (aka invalid characters for a URL can be matched as well).
See [a demo on regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/aI4uW3/2).

Comment: Thank you, but how would I combine it with the regex I had initially linked? Simply adding `(https?:\/\/\S+)` to it doesn't add that support. This is the initial regex I had: `[^\w\s]|\W*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b` https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/9

Comment: @mariocatch: What exactly are you trying to do? The above regex simply matches a string starting with `http://` or `https://`. Your initial request was to match an URL which it does. Putting everybit of logic into one regex makes it unreadable in most of the cases.

Comment: I'm trying to take everything that https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/9#javascript has, and also have it match the URL within that string. Remove special characters, allow the term `3D` to pass, remove money amounts, and remove URLs. I'm not concerned with a readable regex, as I'll just have to apply multiple rules to the same string in the end anyways. May as well do it all at once.

Comment: Looks like this regex works, adding yours to what I had: `(https?:\/\/\S+)|[^\w\s]|\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b` Seen here: https://regex101.com/r/lS4gQ4/1

Comment: @mariocatch: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

[More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url):

Answer (score 0):

You could try this Regex :

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex

```
((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)
```

I have tested it with you string. Test it at https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/8

Comment: This removes the initial regex logic I had. My issue was combining what I had with the URL matcher. https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/9

Comment: What are you trying to do in complete?

Comment: I'm trying to take everything that https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/9 has, and also have it match the URL within that string. Remove special characters, allow the term `3D` to pass, remove money amounts, and remove URLs.